# Validate the date format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, date, datetime

I have the grid cell value to validate for a correct format as below

Date value should be in `DD-MON-YYYY` format and for this i am using below validation

```
Public Function ValidateDateForError(ByVal checkInputValue As String) As Boolean
   Dim returnError As Boolean
    Dim dateVal As DateTime
    If Date.TryParseExact(checkInputValue, "DD-MON-YYYY",
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
           DateTimeStyles.None, dateVal) Then
        returnError = True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("not converted")
    End If
    Return returnError
End Function`
```

DateTime value should be in `DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS` format and for this i am using below validation

```
Public Function ValidateDateTimeForError(ByVal checkInputValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim returnError As Boolean
    Dim dateVal As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(checkInputValue, "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, dateVal) Then
        returnError = True
    End If
    Return returnError
End Function`
```

EDate (valid European date) value should be in `DD/MM/YY` format and for this i am using below validation

```
 Public Function ValidateEDateForError(ByVal checkInputValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim returnError As Boolean
    Dim dateVal As Date
    If Date.TryParseExact(checkInputValue, "DD/MM/YY",
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
           DateTimeStyles.None, dateVal) Then
        returnError = True
    End If
    Return returnError
End Function`
```

JDate (valid Julian date) value should be in `MM/DD/YY` format and for this i am using below validation

```
 Public Function ValidateJDateForError(ByVal checkInputValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim returnError As Boolean
    Dim dateVal As Date
    If Date.TryParseExact(checkInputValue, "MM/DD/YY",
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
           DateTimeStyles.None, dateVal) Then
        returnError = True
    End If
    Return returnError
End Function`
```

but none of above is working. could anyone tell me where i am making mistake?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: as far as I know, "DD-MON-YYYY" is not a valid format, try "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: @Plutonix - still didn't work after changing "DD-MON-YYYY" to "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: define "did not work" you should have been getting "String is not in that format" also, what is the string you are using to test?  ParseExact means you will provide the EXACT format mask. A date of "19-7-2014" will fail because the date is "d-M-yyyy" ("MM" means it will always be a 2 digit month as in "19-07-2014" and 2 digit day "04-07-2014").  Try "d-M-yyyy" for starters on todays date

Comment: What lead you think that "MI" is the format string for minutes? You can look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the correct values to use, and please note that they are case-sensitive. It also has links to the documentation for the DateTime.ParseExact and DateTime.TryParseExact methods, which you may find useful.

Comment: Do you intend to return `True` when the parse succeeded? The names of the functions suggests they return `True` if there is an error. Perhaps `IsValidDate` etc. would be more descriptive.

Comment: now for "dd-MM-yyyy" is working for DATE format and dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss is working for DATETIME format. rest of validation still not working after changing "YY" to "yy" for EDATE and JDATE formats.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - yes, when it will parse successfully then i want to return true else False. yeah i will change the function name as you have suggested. thanks.

Comment: I dunno what a "euro" date is because the French and Germans have very different ideas about that. "dd/MM/yy" and/or "d/M/yy" are valid formats for something like "11/02/14" and "11/2/14".  Julian is usually expressed as "yyDDD" where DDD is 0-366 representing the Day of the year.  Your JDate looks like a US Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ParseExact` means that you will be telling it the precise format the string will be in.  These are case sensitive to allow things like `H` vs `h` for 12/24 clock and `MM` vs `mm` to distinguish Month from Minutes.  So, "DD-MON-YYYY" is invalid, "dd-MM-yyyy" may be what you are after.

But, this means the user would always have to enter 2 digits for the day and month as in "19-07-2014" or "04-07-2014" which they are often not inclined to do, and seems harsh to impose.  `TryParseExact` will take an array of formats so you can be flexible:

```vb
 Dim strFoo As String = "19-7-2014"        ' d-MM-yyyy
 Dim strBar As String = "19-07-2014"       ' dd-MM-yyyy
 Dim strJuly4 As String = "4-7-2014"       ' d-M-yyyy

 ' several possible format styles
 Dim formats() As String = {"d-MM-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", 
      "dd-M-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy"}

 Dim thisDt As DateTime

 ' this should work with all 3 strings above
 If DateTime.TryParseExact(strFoo, formats,
                           Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, thisDt) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Success! {0}", thisDt.ToString)

End If
```

Most of the time there it is silly to force them to enter "04" for a month or day and `d/M/yyyy` will work with strings with the leading "0" (but not the reverse!). Its is added here mainly to show how to pass an array of format patterns.

**DO** consult MSDN for the proper [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

As for Julian Dates, *one* form of them is to use the form `yyDDD` to denote the 2 digit year and day of year for the last 3 digits.  I dont know if the convention for this changed after 1/1/2000 when all Julian for this Century would sort below those for the 1990s.  Still, here is how it is done:

```
Dim jdt As DateTime = #2/11/2010#
Dim jdate As String = xdt.Year.ToString & xdt.DayOfYear.ToString("000")
' ===>  '2010042   or 42nd day of 2010

jdate = (xdt.Year - 2000).ToString("00") & xdt.DayOfYear.ToString("000")
' ===>  '10042   or 42nd day of 2010
```