# check string input for datetime format specific

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have user input that needs to be verified that the string is in the datetime format as follows:
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

The user does not have a choice for any other format but for error checking how do I detect whether string in is this format.

```
 sDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

startdate is the string.

Comment: `ParseExact` doesnt check string input, it converts it to a date if it matches.  Use `InvariantCulture` unless that is a valid for the culture.  You might also want to use `TryParseExact` for when it is NOT in that format (this will return False rather than throw an exception).  There really is little reason to force users to enter dates in any format since you can convert to date from any valid format for the current culture or format  see if these help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24842159/1070452 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757210/1070452

Comment: thanks. This is just a simple console script and I realize with forms I can dictate format. Will use your suggestion. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to convert the date into the format which which you wanted to check

```
 Dim format As String = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 'let input be "02-02-2014 12:12:12"
 MsgBox(dt.ToString(format)) ' the output will be 2014-02-02 12:12:12
```

it works properly in VS 2010(windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should consider using `DateTimePicker` control for taking date/time input. Use `Custom Format` (if needed). It will save you to first take it and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` if you want the date/time format to be exactly in a particular format.

```
Function IsValidDate(ByVal dateValue As String) As Boolean
    Return DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, Nothing)
End Function
```